# Could not find '+' that accepts the supplied arguments

Tags: swift, xcode6

I am trying to make a monthly Loan payment calculator 
here is the code for it:

```
import UIKit

class monthlypayment: UIViewController {



@IBOutlet weak var loanamounttextfield: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var numberofmonthstextfield: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var loanpercentagetextfield: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var answerlabel: UILabel!

@IBAction func calculate(sender: AnyObject) {
    var loanamounttext = loanamounttextfield.text
    var loanamount:Double! = Double((loanamounttext as NSString).doubleValue)
    var loanpercentage = loanpercentagetextfield.text
    var loanpercentagedouble:Double! = Double((loanpercentage as NSString).doubleValue)
    var numbrofmonths = numberofmonthstextfield.text
    var numberofmonths:Double! = Double((numbrofmonths as NSString).doubleValue)
    var rate = loanpercentagedouble/1200
    var monthlypayment:Double = rate+(rate/(1.0+rate)^numberofmonths)-1.0*loanamount
    }
}
```

I get the error here

```
        var rate = loanpercentagedouble/1200
        var monthlypayment:Double = rate+  (rate/(1.0+rate)^numberofmonths)-1.0*loanamount
```

Where numberofmonths and loanamount are doubles as you can see

But I am getting the error:
Could not find '+' that accepts the supplied arguments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Swift `^` is the XOR operator (which return various flavours of Ints) not the exponential, you want to use the `pow(num, power)` function instead

`var monthlypayment = rate + pow(rate / (1.0 + rate), numberofmonths) - 1.0 * loan amount`

Alternatively you can define a custom operator

```
infix operator ** { associativity left precedence 160 }

func ** (left: Double, right: Double) -> Double {
    return pow(left, right)
}
```

And rewrite your code to a more readable

```
var monthlypayment = rate + (rate / (1.0 + rate)) ** numberofmonths - 1.0 * loanamount
```

Comment: I didn't understand what that means and how to use it, can you please explain how i could use it in the code?